# ImageView.getLeft() still produce the original position after property animations

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview

I have 9 ImageView(s), 8 of them are clickable, while imageView9 isn't clickable, and when each clickable imageView is clicked, it will swap its position with imageView9 using property animations.
From what I understood, if I use property animations on an ImageView, it should also update the actual position of the ImageView. However, in this case, each imageView will move to the original position if imageView9, even though imageView 9 already moved to the position of the clicked imageView. What am I missing here ??

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView5, imageView6, imageView7, imageView8, imageView9;
    int x, y, lMargin, tlMargin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
        imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5);
        imageView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image6);
        imageView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image7);
        imageView8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image8);

        // imageView9 is not clickable, when other imageView is clicked,
        // The clicked imageView swaps its position with imageView9
        imageView9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image9);

        imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView5.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView6.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView7.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView8.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get position of imageView9
        lMargin = imageView9.getLeft();

        // Get position of currently clicked imageView
        tlMargin = v.getLeft();

        ObjectAnimator blockAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "x", lMargin);
        blockAnim.setDuration(1000);
        blockAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
        blockAnim.start();

        ObjectAnimator emptyAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.image9), "x", tlMargin);
        emptyAnim.setDuration(1000);
        emptyAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
        emptyAnim.start();

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="100dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image9"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_marginTop="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="0px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="0px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100px"
            android:background="@color/green"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image7"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
            android:background="@color/green"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image8"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_marginTop="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me point out my mistakes, or any better explanation is greatly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: tried `translationX` ?

Comment: you mean instead of using getLeft(), use getTranslationX() on view and imageView9 ?

Comment: no,  i mean property name

Comment: okay I just tried changing ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationX", lMargin) as you suggested, still does not work out.

Comment: I think it got the real position right, but the animation wrong.

Comment: so try getX,  getTranslationX,  not getLeft

Comment: somehow using getTranslationX returns 0 for the position and nothing move, using getX behaves the same way as getLeft. I think it made the imageView to move relative to their original position, not the parent.